# What am I doing wrong with my plot on MATLAB? Linear difference question

Tags: education, matlab, math-software

so I am currently trying to finish off a z-transforms question but I am stuck on why my plot isn't working if someone would be able to give me a hand.

I will just post my question/work so that people can see what I have done thus far, in case that helps to see what I am trying to accomplish, hopefully everything looks good as I am just hoping to fix the plot.

Also as a heads up, both codes have been combined incase it looks confusing at all, I usually just run either or, but was testing something at the time.

Any help/advice on what I have done wrong will be appreciated!

[Image of code and ans in live script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV2rO.png)

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDT0Z.png)

[Work thus far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSBiO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You try to plot an array containing symbolic variables. Referring to your "Image of code and ans in live script": The substitution of s(0) and s(1) in line 16 does not change anything, because s(0) and s(1) already have been substituted by a and b in line 13. Either comment out line 13 or change line 16 to sSol = subs(sSol,[a,b],[0,1]) to get only numeric values to plot.